ClickHouse java client - reusing same instance of ClickHouseClient gives execution timeout after 10 inserts
I am new using clickhouse and I have assembled a project in java using java client.
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
   <artifactId>clickhouse-http-client</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>

HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
   options.put("user", "user");
   options.put("password", "pass");

   String url = "my-clickhouse-host";
   ClickHouseNode server = ClickHouseNode.of(url, options);
   ClickHouseRequest<?> read = ClickHouseClient.builder()
    .nodeSelector(ClickHouseNodeSelector.of(ClickHouseProtocol.HTTP))
    .option(ClickHouseClientOption.SOCKET_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .build()
    .read(server).write();

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String field1 = "field1" + (i);
        String field2 = "field2" + (i);
        String field3 = "field3" + (i);
        String field4 = "field4" + (i);

        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                id,
                field1,
                field2,
                field3,
                field4);

        read.format(ClickHouseFormat.CustomSeparated)
                    .query(query)
                    .executeAndWait();

    }

This code only inserts 10 records, after that I get an Code: 159. Execution timed out Exception
I have already tried to change and add some ClickHouseClientOptions but I always get the same behaviour. How can I reuse the same client connections in clickhouse using java client?

It's better to use batch insert, otherwise, each separate insert would generate a single partition, which is not the intended use in CH. But I am not sure whether it is related to the exception occurred.

@jsc0218 I agree that it is better to batch insert, this is the recommended way described in clickhouse documentation. But is inserting like this (individual records) a limitation of clickhouse? If I reduce for loop to 10 or less the program exists successfully, but if i is greather than 10, I get this exception

I am pretty sure the single insert is not CH designed case. So probably in your case there is some configuration related, for example, some setting related to background merge might raise the exception.
